# xml serialization of a List without a Class object

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

So I am familar with the XmlArray Attribute and it works great when I am serializing a Class, but now I am tasked with just serializing a piece of a class, a List of Int to be exact

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class InvoiceList

    <XmlArray("InvoiceList")> _
    <XmlArrayItem("InvoiceId")> _
    Public m_List As List(Of Integer)
```

If I serialize the entire class the alias works great but if I do

```
serializer = New XmlSerializer(m_List.GetType())
serializer.Serialize(stream, m_List)
```

I get the

```
<ArrayOfInt>
    <int>
```

How can I apply a alias just to a property?

I am looking for

```
<InvoiceList>
  <InvoiceId>
```

Comment: BTW, `SerializableAttribute` is ignored by XML Serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
XmlSerializer Constructor (Type, XmlAttributeOverrides)
```

which allows you to specify the xml attributes, you could either read them using reflection from your example class - or specify them explicitly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfaxz1a0.aspx

The problem was that by specify type to list the attributes of your class are unknown - they belong only to your class